# Why is delete operator required for virtual destructors

Tags: c++, delete-operator, virtual-destructor

In a freestanding context (no standard libraries, e.g. in operating system development) using g++ the following phenomenon occurs:

```
class Base {
public:
   virtual ~Base() {}
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    ~Derived() {}
};

int main() {
    Derived d;
}
```

When linking it states something like this: `undefined reference to operator delete(void*)`

Which clearly means that g++ is generating calls to delete operator even though there are zero dynamic memory allocations. This doesn't happen if destructor isn't virtual.

I suspect this has to do with the generated vtable for the class but I'm not entirely sure. **Why does this happen?**

If I must not declare a delete operator due to the lack of dynamic memory allocation routines, **is there a work around?**

**EDIT1:**

To successfully reproduce the problem in g++ 5.1 I used:

g++ -ffreestanding -nostdlib foo.cpp

Comment: I can’t reproduce the problem for this simple example. Are you sure you’re not missing something?

Comment: @RobinKrahl did you try adding -ffreestanding to the g++ command line. Check on the disassembly dump if there are any calls to delete operator.

Comment: Compiles using g++ 4.8.4 on my Linux Mint. Used `g++ Testing.cpp -ffreestanding`. But with clang 3.5.0 I am getting a bunch of linker errors.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question: What does -nostdlib do ??? (remove operator delete(void*) ? )

Comment: @DieterLücking It skips linking standard C++ library (STL, default operators, personalities, exception handling, stack unwinding and so on)

Comment: @DieterLucking Yes. Usually c++ programs are linked against c++ library, but when developing an operative system you don't have any of those libraries, so there is not default implementation of the operator delete

Comment: @StenSoft sorry, I misread your comment

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because of deleting destructors. That are functions that are actually called when you call `delete obj` on an object with virtual destructors. It calls the complete object destructor (which chains base object destructors — the ones that you actually define) and then calls `operator delete`. This is so that in all places where `delete obj` is used, only one call needs to be emitted, and is also used to call `operator delete` with the same pointer that was returned from `operator new` as required by ISO C++ (although this could be done more costly via `dynamic_cast` as well).

It's part of the [Itanium ABI](https://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html) that GCC uses.

I don't think you can disable this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Agree with @Yakk. Now I get what happens. You think is there a workaround

Comment: @Felipe since the deleting destructor will only be called from a `delete`, and since you don't have one, you could implement your own `delete(void*)` and have it do nothing or generate a runtime error.

Comment: @MarkRansmo You are saying that there is no chance it gets called by a normal destruction of a derived class?

Comment: @Felipe No, deleting destructors are called only with `delete`

Comment: That's the solution then. Thanks

Comment: @MarkRansom out of curiosity, in OP's main function he didn't use the delete operator, so the deleting constructor shouldn't be called in this case, should the delete operator be implemented nonetheless? Or is there something I've misunderstood?

Comment: @Ediac the idea is to provide a dummy function to eliminate the linker error, since the function should never be called anyway. I suggested having it generate an error so that it's easy to detect if someone modifies the code and tries to use `delete` in the future.

Comment: I think there is an additional reason you didn't mention (explicitly): It is possible to overload `operator delete` in a derived class; the standard [class.free]p4 requires that `delete` is dispatched dynamically (effectively) *if the static type of the `delete` operand **has a virtual dtor***. That is, if you define a virtual destructor, you'll effectively also get a virtual `operator delete`. [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0cb0d7aeced8caa0)

Comment: I had this same question (which arose when I upgraded from GCC 4.9 to GCC 5.4.1). Are we saying that there is one call that is made when either delete is called on one of these objects or it goes out of scope? In the latter case what pointer would be passed to `delete`?

Answer (score 1):

In C++20 there is now a fix: [P0722R3](https://wg21.link/p0722r3). The `static void operator delete(T*, std::destroying_delete_t)` deallocation function. It essentially maps to the destroying destructor.

You can just make it not call `::operator delete`, like:

```cpp
class Base {
public:
    void operator delete(Base* p, std::destroying_delete_t) {
        // Shouldn't ever call this function
        std::terminate();  // Or whatever abort-like function you have on your platform

        // The default implemenation without any overrides basically looks like:
        // p->~Base(); ::operator delete(p);
        // Which is why the call to `operator delete` is generated
    }
    virtual ~Base() {}
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    // Calls Base::operator delete in deleting destructor, so no changes needed
    ~Derived() {}
};

int main() {
    Derived d;
}
```

---

The deleting destructor is the one called when you do `delete ptr_to_obj;`. It can only be called by `delete` expressions, so if you have none in your code, this should be fine. If you do, you can replace them with `::delete ptr_to_obj;` and the deleting destructor will no longer be called (it's purpose is to call overriden `operator delete`'s for classes, and `::delete` will only call the global `::operator delete`)